# Similar triangles angles

Tags: geometry

Why in similar triangles the angles measure are the same?

I mean, if I am given two similar triangles and I measure the angles, they will be the same but my question is why? Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: In similar triangles, the ratios of corresponding sides are the same. So the trig ratios are the same as well.

Answer (score 1):

By moving one of the triangles, you may assume that $A'=A$ and $B$ is between $A$ and $B$ and $C'$ between $A$ and $C$. Let $P$ be the intersection of the parallel to $BC$ through $B'$. Then corresponding angles in $ABC$ and $A'B'P$ are equal. By the intercept theorem, $B'P:A'P:A'B'=BC:AC:AB=B'C':A'C':A'B'$, hence $A'P=A'C'$ and $P=C'$

Answer (score 0):

In essence, the definition of similarity is that corresponding angles are the same measure. The byproduct of the angles being the same is that the corresponding sides are proportional. One main way you prove 2 triangles to be similar is by showing that corresponding angles are equal, since that is the definition of similarity. In other words, if you are told (or deduce) that two triangles are similar, then by definition the corresponding angles are equal; and if you are supposed to prove two triangles are similar, simply show the angles are equal.

In contrast, the the definition of *congruence* is that corresponding sides are the same length; the byproduct of this is that corresponding angles are the same measure. Therefore, congruent figures are (trivially) similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two similar triangles and you measure the angles they will be same because similar triangles are the triangles which are different in their sizes but they looks like the same.

For example : Two similar triangles ABC and A'B'C' are shown in the figure.

[image]

If we arrange the triangle A'B'C' inside the triangle ABC, we can see that $\angle BAC \;\&\; \angle B'A'C'$ are the common angle.

[image]

Similarly, $\angle ABC\; \&\; \angle A'B'C'$, and $\angle ACB\; \&\; \angle A'C'B'$ are common as shown in figure as-

[image]

[image]

Therefore the angles of similar triangles are the same.